# SQL Server : query runs very slowly (up to 20 seconds)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I come here now with a problem with "my" database query. It executes for about 22-25 seconds on "cold" database and I'm desperately looking for any way to improve it.

I'd love to skip any table-related suggestions simply because I can't change its structure (too bad). I have what I've been given and well... I'm just trying to find any solution to improve the performance of this query. I'm aware the database is not well-designed, but at the moment I can't do nothing about that, so I'll accept if there's no way to improve the query.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON;

SELECT <STUFF TO SELECT>
FROM [dbo].[2009_Zlecenia] AS Z 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 M1.DataDo AS 'DataRozladunku', M1.Kod, M1.Miasto, MK1.Skrot FROM [dbo].[MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku] AS M1 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Kraje] AS MK1 ON M1.Kraj = MK1.Id WHERE M1.Zlecenie = Z.Id AND M1.Rodzaj = 2 ORDER BY Data DESC) AS MZR 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 M2.DataDo AS 'DataZaladunku', M2.Kod, M2.Miasto, MK2.Skrot FROM [dbo].[MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku] AS M2 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Kraje] AS MK2 ON M2.Kraj = MK2.Id WHERE M2.Zlecenie = Z.Id AND M2.Rodzaj = 1 ORDER BY Data ASC) AS MZR1 
OUTER APPLY (Select count(FP1.Id) 'Count' FROM [dbo].[2009_FakturyPrzewoznika] AS FP1 WHERE FP1.ZlecenieId = Z.Id group by FP1.ZlecenieId) AS FP 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT count(FP3.ZlecenieId) 'Count' FROM [dbo].[2009_FakturyPrzewoznika] AS FP3 WHERE FP3.ZlecenieId IN (Select Id FROM [dbo].[2009_Zlecenia] WHERE IdZlecenieNadrzedne <> 0 And IdZlecenieNadrzedne = Z.Id) GROUP BY FP3.ZlecenieId) AS FP2 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Nr FROM [dbo].[2009_KartyDrogowe] AS KD1 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ZleceniaKartyDrogowej] AS ZKD1 ON ZKD1.KartaDrogowa = KD1.Id WHERE ZKD1.Zlecenie = Z.Id) AS KD 
OUTER APPLY ( Select count(Id) 'Count' FROM [dbo].[2009_Zlecenia] WHERE IdZlecenieNadrzedne <> 0 And IdZlecenieNadrzedne = Z.Id) AS ZP 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ZleceniaWalutaObca] AS ZWO ON Z.Id = ZWO.OrderId 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Kraje] AS K1 ON Z.TransportZ = K1.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Kraje] AS K2 ON Z.TransportDo = K2.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Lista] AS L1 ON Z.Status = L1.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Uzytkownicy] AS U ON Z.Uzytkownik = U.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Oddzialy] AS UO ON U.Oddzial = UO.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FakturyZlecen] AS FZ ON FZ.Zlecenie = Z.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FakturyZlecen] AS FZ1 ON FZ1.Zlecenie = Z.IdZlecenieNadrzedne 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[2009_Faktury] AS F1 ON FZ.Faktura = F1.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[2009_Faktury] AS F2 ON FZ1.Faktura = F2.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Firmy] AS FO ON FO.Id = Z.ZleceniodawcaId 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Uzytkownicy] AS O1 ON FO.Opiekun1 = O1.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Uzytkownicy] AS O2 ON FO.Opiekun2 = O2.Id 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Uzytkownicy] AS O3 ON FO.Opiekun3 = O3.Id 
WHERE Z.TypZlecenia = 4 AND Z.Importowane=0 ORDER BY YEAR(Z.DataZlecenia) DESC, Z.Idx DESC, Z.Nr DESC


SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
SET STATISTICS PROFILE OFF;
```

I would post execution plan, but it's quite big. I will answer keenly any questions regarding it tho! :)

About 80% of query time is consumed by sorting within outer apply clauses.

Here are statistics from execution on "hot" server:

> (16467 row(s) affected)
>
> Table 'Uzytkownicy'. Scan count 0, logical
>   reads 33042, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'Firmy'. Scan
>   count 0, logical reads 50421, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table '2009_Faktury'. Scan count 0, logical reads 48577, physical
>   reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads
>   0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical
>   reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0,
>   lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'FakturyZlecen'.
>   Scan count 32934, logical reads 101846, physical reads 0, read-ahead
>   reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead
>   reads 0.
>
> Table 'Oddzialy'. Scan count 1, logical reads 32935, physical
>   reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads
>   0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'Lista'. Scan count 0, logical reads
>   32934, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'Kraje'. Scan count 2,
>   logical reads 65874, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical
>   reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table
>   'ZleceniaWalutaObca'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table **'Worktable'**. Scan count 65420, **logical reads**
>   **450989**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table '2009_Zlecenia'. Scan
>   count 32635, logical reads 84027, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads
>   0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'ZleceniaKartyDrogowej'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0, physical
>   reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads
>   0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table '2009_FakturyPrzewoznika'. Scan count
>   318, logical reads 687, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob
>   logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table
>   'MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku'. Scan count 2, logical reads 5670,
>   physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 1547 ms,  elapsed time =
>   1771 ms.

I highlighted the "worktable" as I believe that's the main reason for such a bad performance.

Any suggestions that would help??

@EDIT

Execution Plan is here:

[image: Overview]
[image: ExecPlan]
[image: ExecPlan2]
[image: ExecPlan3]

Comment: The execution plan would be nice though, maybe use SQL Sentry Plan Explorer for it to display it?

Comment: And where is Worktable in your select statement?

Comment: Worktables are temporary tables created by SQL Server on tempdb to perform tempory work - `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` etc. See [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181037%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). 
My guess with your query is the series of `OUTER APPLY` statements. If you post the execution plan we can see if there are any obvious bottlenecks regarding missing indexes etc

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the data in smaller parts? Since you have that many tables in the select optimizer might not be able to get the best plan (the plan can even timeout, you can check that from the first node of actual plan)

Comment: Lets consider just the first two `OUTER APPLY` (in an effort to write this in a different way). This implies that the set inside the outer apply returns more than one row. Is this because there is a one-many between `2009_Zlecenia` and `MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku` or is there a one to many between `MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku` and `Kraje`.. or both? Also have you tried ordering by just `Z.DataZlecenia` instead of  `YEAR(Z.DataZlecenia)` ?

Comment: I would also check index usage in those tables that have relatively large amount of reads, maybe there's something that could be fixed there, for example adding include fields to index get rid of key lookups.

Comment: Well, I'll try to get the execution plan posted then :) @JamesZ I thought of indexes too; @Nick it's the way that `MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku` can have multiple rows for each`2009_Zlecenia` and then it requires data from `Kraje` ;> should that (`Kraje`) be joined outside the `OUTER APPLY` clause?? I have tried to order by `Z.DataZlecenia` but it doesn't affect the performance.

Comment: One way to remove the outer apply is pre-clean it in a subtable. `SELECT M1.Zlecenie, M1.DataDo AS 'DataRozladunku', M1.Kod, M1.Miasto, ROW_NUMBER OVER(<some magic here>) RN FROM [dbo].[MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku] AS M1 AND M1.Rodzaj IN (1,2)` is your subtable then you join to that on `M1.Zlecenie`, and `RN=1`. Something like that. It might not make any difference to the query plan though. Are temp tables an option? Do you know what's feeding the worktable?

Comment: This is the concept I'm getting at: http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/. It's a big read but it shows a method of turning outer apply into a join on a subtable with `ROW_NUMBER`..... which _might_ be quicker or might not

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid I have tried to use temptable already but it gave me even worse results - I needed two tables, because in two `Outer Apply` the sorting is different - I needed a primary key (I believe so) to maintain the order, otherwise I'd have to sort it every row anyway to get what I needed. I'll have a look on link provided, but I am afraid that won't do it ;< P.S. Added execution plan

Comment: Several index spools already in that part that's visible, you should really check the indexes in the tables.

Comment: @JamesZ seen them already ;) I'm not SQL expert really, would You point me to a brief tutorial on how these should be set up properly? I've eliminated some of them already, but now I see they take up most of execution time.

Comment: Index spool is an operator where SQL server builds a temporary index in tempdb -- and for getting rid of them either just an index with the where clause fields, or maybe those + the fields in select as include columns is something that could be tested. Don't remember if you can see the index it creates from the actual plan operator properties.

Comment: One more thing, the count -clauses. Do you need to count those exactly those fields that are listed there (=non null values) or could you replace it with count(*)? That helps especially if the fields allow nulls.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot and try to index those - I basically have no idea what should I index, therefore I'm glad You told me what to index. And well, I don't need to count these fields, I could use `count(*)` actually, I just had no idea it matters :) I'll give those suggestions a shot tomorrow and update on my question.

Comment: I'm now implementing Your suggestions @JamesZ and I had a thought for a moment, would that be alright to add fields for `MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku` to `2009_Zlecenia` to store the id of a row that should be joined? Therefore removing the need of `OUTER APPLY` there ;> these could be updated with a trigger on `MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku` update

Comment: @JamesZ would you post the summary of your thoughts so I can mark it as an answer to my question?? I had no time really during last days, but indexing made lots of improvements not only to that query, but few other as well. Thanks a lot ;) there's a boost of 400% of that one alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plan seem to contain a lot of `index spools`, which is an operator where SQL Server builds a temporary index into tempdb. At least for those cases permanent index should improve the performance a lot.

When doing `select count(column)` SQL Server calculates the non-null values of that column. When `select count(*)` is used then the number of rows is calculated and SQL Server can just do an index scan for any index.

It is good to check key lookups from the plan, and if there are such lookups where actual execution count is high, adding those columns as an included field in the index removes the key lookup. This has additional cost for inserts / updates.

Also breaking the one big query into smaller pieces can help the optimizer to choose a better plan. In queries with several big tables it is also possible that the query plan creation ends in a timeout causing really bad plans. This can be seen in the properties of the first node of the query plan ("Optimization level")

Answer (score 2):

You definitly have to get rid of the sub selects. They are executed everytime you iterate a row. You should try to left join them which won't be easy because I see you limit them by select top 1.

**The bad performance is the use of sub selects.**

I do not know the structure and what you may do in one glance but maybe this simple hint will get you to your solution.

Let us consider **one row** that is loaded.

- You load the row from [2009_Zlecenia]
- You load **ALL** of the subselect MZR,
- you sort MZR
- you flush all lines but the first of MZR2
- You load **ALL** of the subselect MZR2,
- you sort MZR2
- you flush all lines but the first of MZR2
- You load **ALL** of the subselect FP1,
- you sort FP1
- you flush all lines but the first of FP1
- You load **ALL** of the subselect FP2,
- you sort FP2
- you flush all lines but the first of FP2
- You load **ALL** of the subselect KD,
- you sort KD
- you flush all lines but the first of KD
- You load **ALL** of the subselect ZP,
- you sort ZP
- you flush all lines but the first of ZP

You do 10 left joins (fast) only once for all, but think about the data that is loaded for every row by the sub selects. They are new loaded every row.

Also **try indexing** of the columns that you filter for: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/alter-table-add-index.html
Indexes will boost execution time on memory and harddisk loss.

Comment: I agree, subselects, especially TOP 1 is killing his performance..  I also think downvoters should comment on why the downvote.

Comment: Do you advise any other way to do so? I'm aware that I load all data for each row (I see that on execution plan when I look at number of execution), but I have no idea how to overcome that ;>

Comment: You have to left join the tables and their joined tables. Make sure you alter  your where / on statement so that you can say it is 1 or 0 lines containing. I do not know your data and cannot tell if this is possible.

Comment: Another speedup: you can speed up if you know that all dates are in the last 7 days. So you can add a where statement with a date filter before ordering the table.

Comment: @Daniel I know nothing about the dates, I could get first and last date by using subquery with "min" and "max" on dates for each row, but would it make that faster? There is no chance I can left join the table, because I have one-to-many between `2009_Zlecenie` and `MiejscaZaladunkuRozladunku` and I have to select first and last with a certain `Rodzaj`. Could that be done with left join?

Comment: Min & max won't make it faster. Try to get a simple `select X from X where X` to fill your needs. If that won't do, you cannot use fast joins.

Comment: Added info about column indexing.